# Get logged in user's name from process running under "run as" credentials

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

One can run exe as user different from currently logged in one (using "run as").

For example I log in as "user1" into Windows and start executable with "run as" using credentials of "User2".

How to retreive user name/identity of "User1" (who logged in currently) and not "User2" (which the process runs under)?

I.e. `System.Environment.UserName` give User2 (as expected).

Comment: `Please provide code` isn't a good way to end a question.

Comment: Please check out if my edit is what you wanted to ask.

Comment: @ Alexei Levenkov yes thats exactly what i wanted ..

Answer (score 4):

You can get the current identity of the user under which the current thread is running (not necessarily the logged in user) using `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`.  Alternatively you can get the logged in user name via the `Environment.UserName` property.  It is not guaranteed to be the user running the current process however.

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I know  this an old question but maybe this solution will be useful for someone.

You can retrieve the current session user (not the user who has runned the app) with "QWinsta" or "Query Session".

This code create a process to run QWinsta with "console" parameter, when you do this you will get a result like:

[image: CMD running QWinsta command with console parameter]

Then you can catch that result with "StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput" and "StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()", split it and search for ">console" and save the index into a variable, finally you can get the user with "index+1" in the split array.

For security i've add "Proc.WaitForExit(2000)" to wait a maximum of 2 seconds before stop the task or it will wait forever and "Proc.ExitCode != 0" to protect against any error can ocurr.

```
Process Proc = new Process();
Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"qwinsta.exe";
Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"console";
Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Proc.Start();
if (!Proc.WaitForExit(2000) || Proc.ExitCode != 0)
{
    try { Proc.Kill(); } catch { }
    return null;
}
string Resultado = Proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string[] Textos = Resultado.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int Indice = 0;
foreach (string TXT in Textos) { if (TXT == ">console") { break; } else Indice++; }
return Textos[Indice + 1];
```

**NOTE: if you want to use "QWinsta" or "Query Session" you can do it in two ways.**

First: Copy QWinsta.exe from

> C:\windows\system32
>   and put it on your app root folder (Remember use always copy option)

Second: Provide UserName and Password to process StartInfo, but you'll need admin credentials and Password must be a "system.Security.SecureString"

**NOTE2: Not all versions of windows have the QWinsta.exe like Windows 10 Student N, but you can copy the "QWinsta.exe" from other windows and use it.**

> **This code has been tested on Win10 and Win8**